# Read data without opening excel file

Tags: c#, .net, database, excel, ado.net

I've a software in which data is stored in Excel database columns are `Product_ID` and `Description`. I've included the searching feature, which displays results based on `Product_ID`.

The problem is it only retrieves data when that Excel file is open, but I want to read data without opening the Excel file. Is there any way to do this?

My code for searching:

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    srch();
}

private void srch()
{            
    DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
    string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= 'c:\\Product Details.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
    string query = "select * from [Sheet1$]" ;

    DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, strConn);
    da.Fill(excelDataSet);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = excelDataSet.Tables[0];
    DataView dv = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;
    DataView dv_filter = new DataView();
    dv_filter.Table = excelDataSet.Tables[0];
    dv_filter.RowFilter = "Product_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv_filter;
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I have seen some solutions using VBA but I still wonder if it can be done in C#